# the difference between 恨めしい and 憎らしい

Tags: word-choice

In this wiki: [https://ja.wiktionary.org/wiki/うらめしい](https://ja.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E3%81%86%E3%82%89%E3%82%81%E3%81%97%E3%81%84), the word "恨めしい" is simply explained as "憎らしい" in one of its items.

Are there any differences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have used a better dictionary. There are better free online ones like デジタル大辞泉. But here's what 明鏡国語辞典 says:

> #### 恨めしい
>
> ①ひどい仕打ち（をした相手）に、怒りや憎しみや不満などを感じる。恨みたくなる気持ちだ。「裏切られたことが━」「一方的な解雇を━・く思う」
>
> ②思い通りにならなくて、残念だ。「足が痛くて歩けないのが━」「己おのれの軽率さ［無情の雨］が━」「恨めしそうに雨天の空を仰ぐ」

One meaning of 恨めしい is like "vengeful". It's a strong word used after someone has been badly affected by someone. Stereotypical Japanese ghosts ([幽霊](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y%C5%ABrei)) use this word often. See also: [Translation of うらめしや](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/54065/5010)

憎らしい is like "odious" or "hateful", and is used in a wider variety of situations. Basically it's an antonym of "lovable". You can safely say 憎らしい笑い方だ when you saw someone for the first time on TV. You can jokingly praise someone like 憎らしいほどに強い "He's so strong I almost hate him".

Comment: Thank you very much. In fact, 憎らしい was firstly encountered in a dialog where the wife scolded her husband, while 恨めしい was firstly encountered in descripting ghosts. Now I understand.