# What's going on with adjectives ending with や?

Tags: i-adjectives, particle-や

I was looking into a presumably older song, Gion Kouta, and I noticed that one of the lyrics is 「恋しや」. I'm assuming this comes from the adjective 「恋しい」, but I don't know why 「や」 is used instead of 「い」. Does 「や」 make 「い」 adjectives into nouns? Is it an older adjective ending? I'm confused about this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Translation of うらめしや](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/54065/translation-of-%e3%81%86%e3%82%89%e3%82%81%e3%81%97%e3%82%84)

Answer (score 4):

恋し　is the classical Japanese form of　恋しい. It is already in its terminal form (終止形) so や is just an exclamation word here.

You can check the conjugation table [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%88%80%E3%81%97#Japanese).

Comment: No, it is not 終止形 but 語幹. The Classical Japanese has シク活用 adjectives where 語幹 is directly 終止形, but not for example: ありがたし > ありがたや.